# Can not include typhoeus into my ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, unicorn, typhoeus

i am trying to include typhoeus like:

```
require 'typhoeus'
```

but i see in log files:

```
/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': No such file to load -- typhoeus (LoadError)
```

I included it to the gem file and i don't know what i do wrong

Comment: Ran the bundle command and restarted the server?

Comment: What is the bundle command?   i restarted and nginx and unicorn servers

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use bundler to install gems on rails projects.
The bundle command installs gems that were added on the Gemfile.

Then you won't need to add require 'typhoeus' if you install it on the project by using [bundler](http://bundler.io/) and installed the typhoeus gem.